# doctrine 2 , deleting row , contraint fails

Tags: doctrine-orm

i tried deleting from a user  , inside the users entity, i have a one to many  property:

```
/** @OneToMany(targetEntity="\Entities\comments", mappedBy="comments", cascade={"persist"}) */
protected $usercomments;
```

as there are comments, i cannot remove the main user... errors:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

i also tried: cascade={"persist", "remove"}  , still no joy when deleting...

do i have to delete all comments for this user first in a loop then remove user as i thought it would delete all related automatically.

Comment: Does any other table reference the table from which you are deleting?

Comment: nope.. just the comments

Answer (score 4):

Try `* @joinColumn(onDelete="SET NULL", onUpdate="SET NULL")`

Comment: theres no join on the users side..  so i cant put this annotation..  i want to use the remove($userentity) this will work if there are no associations attached to it .i.e, in this case, comments...

Comment: you need to put it on the comments side